# blktrace output error in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, devops, blktrace

my docker container base image is ubuntu, and I ran it with full privilege options that means in run command I use these switches:

```
--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined
```

I wanna use blktrce using below command:

```
sudo blktrace -d / -a issue -o - | blkparse -f "%p %T.%9t %D %S ^C %d\n" -i - >stream.out
```

but, first time when is use this command I get this error:

```
Debugfs is not mounted at /sys/kernel/debug
```

i searched and found [this solution](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/BlktraceNotes) which led to use this command:

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

after that, when I use the `blktrace` command again, i get this error:

```
BLKTRACESETUP(2) / failed: 25/Inappropriate ioctl for device
Thread 1 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace1: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 0 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace0: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 2 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace2: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 4 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace4: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 3 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace3: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 5 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace5: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 7 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace7: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 8 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace8: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 6 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace6: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 12 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace12: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 10 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace10: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 13 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace13: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 15 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace15: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 14 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace14: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 17 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace17: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 16 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace16: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 18 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace18: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 11 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace11: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 19 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace19: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 20 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace20: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 9 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace9: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 21 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace21: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 22 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace22: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 23 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace23: 2/No such file or directory
FAILED to start thread on CPU 0: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 1: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 2: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 3: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 4: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 5: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 6: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 7: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 8: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 9: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 10: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 11: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 12: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 13: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 14: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 15: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 16: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 17: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 18: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 19: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 20: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 21: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 22: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 23: 1/Operation not permitted
```

how can i solve that?

**Update1:**

there is `sda` folder in `/sys/kernel/debug/block/` and into this folder there are these files:

```
trace0 trace1 trace2 etc.
```

**Update2:**

@abligh thank for your answer, but did not help. The `strace` output about `ioctl` is:

```
ioctl(3, BLKTRACESETUP, {act_mask=64, buf_size=524288, buf_nr=4, start_lba=0, end_lba=0, pid=0}, 0x7ffe8a4ceac0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(2, "BLKTRACESETUP(2) / failed: 25/Inappropriate ioctl for device\n", 61) = 61
ioctl(3, BLKTRACESTOP, 0x7f6fd19789d0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, BLKTRACESTOP, 0x7ffe8a4ce540) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, BLKTRACESTOP, 0x7f6fd19789e0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`
ioctl(3, BLKTRACETEARDOWN, 0x7f6fd19789e0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

to answer your question about why i run `blktrace` in container, i would say I'm using containers as cluster, so i need the trace of each node.

Comment: Does `blktrace` work from outside the container? I'm guessing the issue might be that the block devices themselves are not visible from the container.

Comment: @abligh yes, it's ok with host.

Comment: then it isn't a kernel lock or similar. I suspect your issue is simply that `BLKTRACESETUP` is not working in a container. This may be a kernel limitation. An `strace` of `blktrace` would be helpful.

Comment: @abligh i think there is no kernel limitation, cuz i run docker container with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN` and `--security-opt  apparmor:unconfined`. sorry did not get your advise, what's an `state` of `blktrace`?

Comment: @abligh does my new update on question help?

Comment: did you mount sysfs in your container before you mounted debugfs? You should ensure that both `/sys` and `/proc` are mounted first.

Comment: @abligh No, I did not. how can i do that?

Comment: something like `mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys ; mount -t proc none /proc` before the debugfs mount.

Comment: @abligh they were mounted already! problem did not solved yet.

Comment: Are the block devices you are trying to trace present in `/sys/block/` in the container? You might add an `strace` of the `blktrace` to the question (i.e. `sudo strace -f -o/tmp/trace blktrace ...` then post `/tmp/trace` somewhere).

Comment: @abligh in `sys/block/` there are these: `loop0  loop1  loop2  loop3  loop4  loop5  loop6  loop7  ram0  ram1  ram10  ram11  ram12  ram13  ram14  ram15  ram2  ram3  ram4  ram5  ram6  ram7  ram8  ram9  sda  sr0` would you please post a clear answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough information to debug this, but you asked for an answer to be posted.

The root of the problem seems to be here:

```
BLKTRACESETUP(2) / failed: 25/Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

This is indicating that the `ioctl` call to set up block tracing is failing. It is failing inside the container, but according to the comments works outside the container. This would indicate that the problem is with the container setup or a limitation in the kernel that prevents that `ioctl` from being used in a container at all.

The error `inappropriate ioctl for device` is errno 25, i.e. `ENOTTY`. I can't immediately see what would be returning that unless it can't find the device node at all (given you've already demonstrated from the fact it works outside the container that the block trace code is compiled in). I can't remember whether this is in a module, but it would be worth trying block tracing outside the container first (then check it inside the container), just to check this isn't a module loading issue.

The first step in debugging this would be to use `strace` tool (as suggested above) so you know exactly which system call is being made with what parameters. EG run:

```
sudo strace -f -s2048 -o/tmp/trace blktrace -d / -a issue -o - | blkparse -f "%p %T.%9t %D %S ^C %d\n" -i - >stream.out
```

and look at `/tmp/trace` afterwards. `strace` will list all the system calls made. See if you can determine from that which `ioctl` is failing.

Secondly, I'd ensure that the block device that you are trying to trace actually appears within the correct place(s) in `/proc/` and `/sys/`. Something wrong is happening here:

```
Thread 0 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace0: 2/No such file or directory
```

Note the `(null)` in the debug line, which clearly should not be there - that should be the name of the block device. This is possibly a consequence of the failed `ioctl`, or possibly indicative of a problem within the `/sys/` hierarchy.

`BLKTRACESETUP` is handled in the kernel [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/trace/blktrace.c#L646). This eventually calls `doblktracesetup` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/trace/blktrace.c#L430). I cannot immediately see any reason why this would not work from an appropriately permissioned container, which makes me suspect your `/sys` hierarchy might not be set up right. But the output of `strace` would be helpful.

Also, the inevitable comment: why are you doing this in a container? Why not run it outside the container?

**EDIT**: Looks like it might be a kernel thing. See https://github.com/scaleway/kernel-tools/issues/107 - this suggests you (a) need to modprobe the specific modules first, and (b) may need a specific kernel.